# Not able to invert colors | xcalib -a -i stopped working

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, colors, monitors

I used the command *xcalib* to invert the colors on my screen and it was working fine for a long time till suddenly somehow it stopped working.I am unable to diagnose as to what has caused this.

Now when I run the command it has no effect on the screen and I get the following message :

```
 xcalib -i -a
Warning - Unable to get display calibration
```

What could have gone wrong? Kindly someone please help.

```
Am using arch
Linux xxxx 5.15.15-1-lts #1 SMP Sun, 16 Jan 2022 09:28:22 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: did you try a reboot before?

Comment: Yes, several times. I am having this issue since several weeks now.

Comment: did you switch the graphics card or TFT screen brand?

Comment: No I have not changed my setup at all both in terms of hardware and software....but have been updating arch regularly.  

My graphics driver - [ VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21) ]

Comment: I have this issue but I don't even get any warnings.

Comment: @Michael Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no, it still doesn't work.  I *think* it was around the time I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 but that may have been coincidental.

Comment: I fixed the issue: redshift will not allow you to invert colors. `killall redshift` and try again. If you're using something similar to redshift such as xflux, kill that isntead. Let me know if this worked

Comment: No I am not using redshift or xflux, They are not installed on the system. But still having this issue :(